# Procedurally create/read from nbt object/dictionary

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a project that requires creating nbt dictionaries from another nbt array.

Essentially, the scenerio is as follows

I have array `[1,2,3,4]` and I would like to create a dictionary `{1:2, 3:4}`

These are just example values and will be generated at runtime

However, I can't figure out a way to create a dictionary procedurally, as the only way I know is to do `/data modify storage <name> <key> set value <value>`

I know I can do `set from` instead, but the main issue is the hardcoded `<key>`. I can't figure out a way to procedurally create/remove a key from a dict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic keys are not a thing in NBT.

You'll have to use this slightly more complex format for a key-value pair dictionary:

```
{
  Database: [
    {key: 1, value: "one"},
    {key: 2, value: "two"},
    {key: 3, value: "three"}
  ]
}
```

…and read/write to it with these commands:

- New K/V pair (static):

  ```
  data modify storage test:main Database append value {key: 4, value: "four"}
  ```
- Read value from key (static):

  ```
  tellraw @a {"nbt":"Database[{key: 4}].value"}
  ```
- Overwrite new value (dynamic) to a key (static):

  ```
  data modify storage test:main Database[{key: 4}].value …
  ```

Commands to do the same operations but with dynamic keys will be much harder but not impossible.
Here is a starter for adding a new key-value pair with dynamic key and value:

```
data modify storage test:main Database append value {key: "temp", value: "temp"}
data modify storage test:main Database[-1].key set value 5
data modify storage test:main Database[-1].value set value "five"
```

Comment: Love this workaround.

Comment: any ideas for the best way to read a dynamic key? I've only come up with copying the dict and cycling through the entries until a key matches a desired value (inefficient to say the least)

Comment: @Jam Honestly ListDB might be a better option, not sure tho